# How to create custom UI components like responsive seekbar?

Tags: android, user-interface, graphics

I want to create custom sliders or seekbars in android (just as in the gif, slider on the bottom and right), could you provide me with any relevant process how to achieve this.[image: custom sliders]

Comment: Why am I being down voted ?

Comment: this has everything https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components

Comment: @MoonisAbidi Hello! have you got any solution for right slider?

Comment: @NaseerAttari What kind of slider are you looking for?

Comment: @MoonisAbidi I'm looking for vertical range slider as same as right slider in your question.

Comment: @NaseerAttari I have written Canvas code for the rounded slider, you could modify it to get a straight one. If you want I can send you the code.

Comment: @MoonisAbidi Yes sure let me try for the straight one. You can share Canvas code naseerattari1@gmail.com

Comment: @MoonisAbidi How did you manage the slider for height?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching for several days I have finally got enough resources to address the problem statement.
For staters go through the following resources:

1) https://guides.codepath.com/android/Basic-Painting-with-Views

2) https://guides.codepath.com/android/Progress-Bar-Custom-View

3) https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components

**Basics Steps -**

- Extend an existing View class or subclass with your own class.
- Override some of the methods from the superclass. The superclass methods to override start with 'on', for example, onDraw(), onMeasure(), and onKeyDown(). This is similar to the on... events in Activity or ListActivity that you override for lifecycle and other functionality hooks.
- Use your new extension class. Once completed, your new extension class can be used in place of the view upon which it was based.

**Below is the code that demonstrate a working Clock in canvas -**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.Calendar;

    /**
     * Created by moonis
     * on 23/06/18.
     */
    public class CustomClock extends View {
        private int height, width = 0;
        private int padding = 0;
        private int fontSize = 0;
        int numeralSpacing = 0;
        private int handTruncation, hourHandTruncation = 0;
        private int radius = 0;

        private Paint paint;

        private boolean isInit;
        private int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
        private Rect rect = new Rect();

        public CustomClock(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            setFocusable(true);
            setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        }

        private void initClock() {
            height = getHeight();
            width = getWidth();
            padding = numeralSpacing + 50;
            fontSize = (int) DeviceDimensionHelper.convertDpToPixel(13, getContext());
            int min = Math.min(height, width);
            radius = min / 2 - padding;
            handTruncation = min / 20;
            hourHandTruncation = min / 7;

            paint = new Paint();
            isInit = false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            if (!isInit) {
                initClock();
            }
            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
            drawCircle(canvas);
            drawCentre(canvas);
            drawNumeral(canvas);
            drawHands(canvas);
            postInvalidateDelayed(500);
        }


        private void drawCircle(Canvas canvas) {
            paint.reset();
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            canvas.drawCircle(width / 2, height / 2, radius + padding - 10, paint);
        }

        private void drawCentre(Canvas canvas) {
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            canvas.drawCircle(width / 2, height / 2, 12, paint);
        }

        private void drawNumeral(Canvas canvas) {
            paint.setTextSize(fontSize);
            for (int number : numbers) {
                String tmp = String.valueOf(number);
                paint.getTextBounds(tmp, 0, tmp.length(), rect);
                double angle = Math.PI / 6 * (number - 3);
                int x = (int) (width / 2 + Math.cos(angle) * radius - rect.width() / 2);
                int y = (int) (height / 2 + Math.sin(angle) * radius - rect.height() / 2);
                canvas.drawText(tmp, x, y, paint);
            }
        }

        private void drawHands(Canvas canvas) {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            float hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            hour = hour > 12 ? hour - 12 : hour;
            drawHand(canvas, (hour + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) / 60) * 5f, true);
            drawHand(canvas, c.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false);
            drawHand(canvas, c.get(Calendar.SECOND), false);
        }

        private void drawHand(Canvas canvas, double loc, boolean isHour) {
            double angle = Math.PI * loc / 30 - Math.PI / 2;
            int handRadius = isHour ? radius - handTruncation - hourHandTruncation : radius - handTruncation;
            canvas.drawLine(width / 2, height / 2, (float) (width / 2 + Math.cos(angle) * handRadius), (float) (height / 2 + Math.sin(angle) * handRadius), paint);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float touchX = event.getX();
            float touchY = event.getY();
            switch (event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    //code to move clock hands on screen gestures
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                   //code to move clock hands on screen gestures
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
            //redraw view
            postInvalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

**Finally this library can be used to achieve the desired output -**

https://github.com/moldedbits/android-dial-picker

Comment: have you checked https://github.com/saulmm/From-design-to-Android-part2

Comment: @MoonisAbidi Ya you lost your points but i think you did a great affort there. Nice work man. Appreciate it. And i'm also not getting why ur question got downvoted.

Comment: @NaseerAttari What kind of slider are you looking for?

Comment: @MoonisAbidi can you share this vertical slider code

Comment: @Arti I have the code for the round slider, you can modify it to make a straight one.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [this](https://github.com/LukeDeighton/WheelView) Wheelview Library to achieve the bottom wheel

and [this](https://github.com/kevalpatel2106/android-ruler-picker) for your vertical ruler

to scale your image horizontally and vertically, probably you might have to go with some sort of custom solution, Vector images would be a suitable fit.

Also refer [this](https://github.com/saulmm/From-design-to-Android-part2)

Hope this helps you.